# Can an Opera speed dial extension be bundled with a regular extension?

Tags: opera-extension

Is there some way to add a speed dial component to an existing extension? Or does the speed dial always have to be a separate extension?

I want to have an extension, but then have a speed dial that communicates with the extension.

Looking at the manifest for the speed dial, it doesn't appear to coexist with a regular extension.

I'm wondering if there is some way to bundle using the NEX format or something like that.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not actually aware what sort of extension and functionality you need but the speed-dial extension can do everything that "regular" extension does. The only difference is that you can't have combination of speed-dial, browser action and page action (all are mutually exclusive).

The speed-dial extension has background page (as regular extension has) and you can put any script you need there (e.g. with <script> tag). It means that you can do much more than just displaying some page/image on the speed-dials page.

Comment: > The only difference is that you can't have combination of speed-dial, browser action and page action (all are mutually exclusive).

That's the issue. I want to have an extension that has an icon on the toolbar for mail checking as well as a speed dial.

I guess that's not possible?

And as far as being able to do anything with a speed dial, the main problem is that all a speed dial can do is navigate to a single URL. There's no way to use a JS listener to catch the click and do something more interesting (in our case, navigate to a POST url for viewing your email).